# C++ | Problems with files

Tags: c++, file

I'm pretty new to C++ and I wanted to start working with files so I ended up doing this :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <limits>
#include <Lmcons.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;


void out(string x){x+="\n";cout<<x;}
void outn(){out("");}
void delay(int x){Sleep(x);}
void delayS(int x){Sleep(x*1000);}
void cs(){std::system("cls");}
void UserName(string *x){char username[UNLEN + 1];DWORD size = UNLEN +  1;GetUserName(username, &size);string transition(username);*x=transition;}
//use this synthax in main :  char user[20];string    username(user);UserName(&username);

using namespace std;

int main()
{
char user[20];string username(user);UserName(&username);
out(username);
delayS(2);
cs();

string beginning="C:\\Users\\" ;
string path;
string ending="\\Desktop\\";
string filename;

out("file name = ");
cin>>filename;

path+=beginning;
out(path);
delayS(2);

path+=username;
out(path);
delayS(2);

path+=ending;
out(path);
delayS(2);

path+=filename;
out(path);
delayS(2);

ofstream file;
try{
    file.open(path ,ios::in);
    if(!file.is_open()){throw 404;}
    else{
    file.open(path,ios::out|ios::app);
    file<<"\n";
    file<<"lol";}


    }catch(int x){cout<<"Error "<<x<<" : file not found";}


    return 0;
}
```

Which result in this error (line 59) :
" no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ofstream::open(std::string&, std::_Ios_Openmode)' "

image of error : https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4kqb.jpg

May I have some help ?

EDIT: I'm using Codeblocks 16.01

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pre-C++11, you need to pass a `const char*` to `ofstream::open()` as the first parameter:

```
file.open( path.c_str(), ios::in );
```

Comment: Getting a new error (added edit to my question) : https://imgur.com/3odU4DA

Comment: Ok I found out ^^ you need to use the c-string thingie aka : c_string() 

`file.open(path.c_str(),ios::in);`

Comment: Edited to fix this.